# Convert Array Surrounded By Single Quotes To An Array

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

Deeply nested in a JSON object I have the property `value`.

```
actions:
    [ { name: 'InviteUser',
        type: 'button',
        value: '[Brian, Timoney, brian@someemaildomain.com,United States, DEM,  edit me, 1580333]' } ],
   callback_id: 'market_invite',
```

pulled out of the nested JSON it looks like:

```
value: '[Brian, Timoney, brian@someemaildomain.com,United States, DEM,  edit me, 1580333]'
```

Is there a simple way to convert this to an array? The array output I am looking for would be:

```
["Brian", "Timoney", "brian@someemaildomain.com", "United States", "DEM", "edit me", "1580333"]
```

Hard to believe I am asking this since it seems very straight-forward but after some time of trying variations of things like `Array.from()` and `JSON.parse()` and trying to find a duplicate question on stack overflow, I am left puzzled.

Comment: Can you be more clear about what you want converted to an array?  Adding the desired output to the post would help a lot.

Comment: @EdBayiates - edited to be more explicit

Comment: The better idea would be to fix whatever program serialised this value into a string.

Comment: So your output would be an array consisting of 6 elements, namely: "Brian", "Timoney", "brian@someemaildomain.com,United States", "DEM",  "edit me", "1580333" ?

Comment: The problem is that the string is not in the form of valid JSON. The "values" are not quoted, so how the strings should be separated is ambiguous. Where does something like that come from in the first place? It might be easier to work on avoiding getting the list in that form in the first place.

Comment: This is coming from slack as a result of a user hitting an interactive button ( not sure why slack developers are serializing it like this ) they usually are really good at this kind of stuff.

Comment: @EdBayiates updated question with desired output

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can simply use the string API. Depending on how certain you are about the characters that might occur in your input (especially commas), the following may be enough:

```
function valueStringToArray(valueString) {
    return valueString.substr(0, valueString.length - 1).substr(1).split(',');
}
```

Answer (score 5):

```js
var obj = {
  actions: [{
    name: 'InviteUser',
    type: 'button',
    value: '[Brian, Timoney, brian@someemaildomain.com,United States, DEM,  edit me, 1580333]'
  }],
  callback_id: 'market_invite'
};

var arr = obj.actions[0].value.replace(/\[|\]/g, "").split(",").map(str => str.trim());

console.log(arr);
```

Comment: The regex removes white space from between "United States". It would probably be better to loop over the array elements and trim() them.

Answer (score 2):

Try using the built in string methods, for example:

```
function parseArrayValues(s) {
  return s.substr(1, s.length-2).split(/\s*,\s*/);
}

parseArrayValues(actions[0].value);
// => ["Brian", "Timoney", "brian@someemaildomain.com", "United States", "DEM", "edit me", "1580333"]
```